# SwifUI: Fullscreen cover radius when swiping

Tags: swiftui

I would like to add corner radius when presenting a fullscreen cover. Just like how Apple do it  in the Music App.
The idea is that the the presented fullscreen cover gets the corner radius only on the top right & left when presenting.
The view will be rounded only when presenting.

Check attached video

[Fullscreen Cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zRKj.jpg)

Comment: Use `.sheet()` instead of `.fullScreenCover()`. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:)).

Comment: .sheet is an other thing. I'm talking about a view that covers an other one

Answer (score 0):

Use this view extension to your project and after that you can add corner to any of the view side.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        clipShape( RoundedCorner(radius: radius, corners: corners) )
    }
}
struct RoundedCorner: Shape {

    var radius: CGFloat = .infinity
    var corners: UIRectCorner = .allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}
```

In you code

```
    var body: some View {
    
    VStack{

    Spacer()

    }.cornerRadius(5, corners: [.topLeft, .topLeft, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight])
               
}
```